# Sync multiple chocolatey repositories

Tags: chocolatey

I was wondering if there is a way for chocolatey to sync multiple repositories to one, in a hub and spoke topology.

I am implementing a chocolatey repo system in my organization, and I need to have repositories located in multiple network segments, across several domains, that are not all in the same forest.  I need to sync packages across all of these repos.

My initial solution was to use DFS, but because I don't have trust throughout the domains that I am working with, that won't be possible.

Is there anything I can do with chocolatey to accomplish this?  Any solutions that I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the realm of Chocolatey, but rather the repository technology that you are using.

For example, Artifactory allows the creation of a proxy repository, or a group repository, that would do exactly what you are asking.  This is also possible in systems like ProGet and Nexus.

Once configured, you could then point Chocolatey at the source (or rather feed) that contains everything that you want.

Have a look here:

https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-host-feed

For more information on the available hosting options.